# Почему у целого числа нельзя вызвать метод напрямую?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вопрос особого практического смысла не имеет, просто стало любопытно, почему в Python нельзя вызвать метод напрямую у числа? Например, я могу сделать это со строкой:

```py
'3'.__add__('4') # 34
```

Или со списком:

```py
[].__add__([3]) # [3]
```

Но не могу сделать так с числом:

```py
3.__add__(4) # SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

При этом я могу записать 3 в переменную и тогда все, естественно, ок:

```py
x = 3
x.__add__(4) #7
```

Comment: Потому что точка воспринимается как десятичный разделитель. В JS помогает поставить пробел перед точкой или поставить две точки или заключить число в скобки. Попробуй что-нибудь из этих вариантов

Comment: `(3).__add__(4)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Потому что с точки зрения парсера у вас написано число (float) `3.`, а за ним вызов `__add__(4)` и получается синтаксическая ошибка. Нужно объяснить парсеру, что вы вовсе не имели в виду число `3.`, например заключив число в скобки или поставив пробел перед точкой:

```
>>> (3).__add__(4)
7
>>> 3 .__add__(4)
7
```

Ещё один вариант `3..__add__(4)` (= `7.0`), но результат будет числом с плавающей точкой, обычно это не то что требуется.